# Angular flickers when authenticating user

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need help eliminating a flicker with Angular. I am getting a flicker every time a new route is passed through. I have a login and logout button outside the ng-view which uses ng-if="authenticated". The problem is any time a menu item is clicked and a new view is displayed the logout or login button flickers. Is there a way to eliminate this? Below is the module, config and run function.

PS. I am very new to Angular. This was a script from a tutorial on using Angular, php and mysql for a login system.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'toaster']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/login', {
            title: 'Login',
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
            controller: 'authCtrl'
        })
        .when('/logout', {
            title: 'Logout',
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
            controller: 'logoutCtrl'
        })
        .when('/signup', {
            title: 'Signup',
            templateUrl: 'views/signup.html',
            controller: 'authCtrl'
        })
        .when('/dashboard', {
            title: 'Dashboard',
            templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'authCtrl'
        })
        .when('/posts', {
            title: 'Posts',
            templateUrl: 'views/posts.html',
            controller: 'authCtrl'
        })
        .when('/stats', {
            title: 'Stats',
            templateUrl: 'views/stats.html',
            controller: 'authCtrl'
        })
        .when('/ambas', {
            title: 'Ambassadors',
            templateUrl: 'views/ambassadors.html',
            controller: 'authCtrl'
        })
        .when('/images', {
            title: 'Images',
            templateUrl: 'views/images.html',
            controller: 'authCtrl'
        })
        .when('/', {
            title: 'Login',
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
            controller: 'authCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/posts'
        });
}])
.run(function ($rootScope, $location, Data) {
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
        $rootScope.authenticated = false;
        Data.get('session').then(function (results) {
            if (results.uid) {
                $rootScope.authenticated = true;
                $rootScope.uid = results.uid;
                $rootScope.name = results.name;
                $rootScope.email = results.email;
            } else {
                var nextUrl = next.$$route.originalPath;
                if (nextUrl == '/signup' || nextUrl == '/login') {

                } else {
                    $location.path("/login");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @bata answered my issues however, I have a new issue now. If the user is logged in and then logs out the login button does not change to the logout button unless I reload the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the authenticated value to false on every route change start. So every time a user clicks to change the route you set it to false, and then a few moments later you set it to true if authentication is fine. That will cause a flicker.

So, remove the `$rootScope.authenticated = false;` from the `$routeChangeStart` callback.

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
    //$rootScope.authenticated = false; <--- *remove this*
    Data.get('session').then(function (results) {
    ...........
```

Comment: Awesome :) thank you so much. I knew it had to be something simple. One more question. If the user is logged out and they are on the login page and they click on any of the menu items it very briefly starts to load the view but then the authentication kicks in

Comment: Well you need to handle it on logout also. So on logout (in your logout method) set the $rootScope.authenticated to false.
I am actually just guessing now, because I don't see that code.

Comment: That worked! Again thank you. what about the briefly trying to load views when authentication is false

Comment: On $routeChangeStart, I would try event.preventDefault() on the begging and then redirect to login if error (you already do that) and if it is a success, then redirect to where the user clicked to go.

Comment: i added event.preventDefault(); just after //$rootScope.authenticated = false; but I am still getting the same resutls